# Generate project/class diagram from eclipse/android environment

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, windows, uml

I'm looking for `tool/plugin` which makes possible automatic generating any kind of `UML diagram` with connections between `classes/activities/files/views` (java).

It might be pretty simple just to make a scratch in bigger `project`. Sometime it's hard to embrace when developer is new in something bigger.

Both `windows` and `linux` platforms are welcome.

**EDIT:**

I am interrested in uml's for android only. Before we've used inteliJ from jetbrains which worked pretty good, but it's embedded tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [ObjectAid UML Explorer](http://www.objectaid.com/home) for Eclipse.